# Data Scraping From Website Having Captcha

Tags: web-scraping, captcha

Hello i want Scrape the Data Automatically From Websites Having captcha Like : [Result Website](http://www.gturesults.in/)
I want to copy all data to a excel file.

Any one have good suggestion for me , which have less coding.

i Have also used OutWit Hub , but it is a manually scraping and i am not satisfied with that.

Comment: get the screen shot of the website and try to identify text in the captcha by some pattern recognition phenomena

Comment: and what about data scrapping??

Comment: You can use Jsoup, if interested in java...else for scraping with python ,you can use Scrapy

Comment: Jsoup :http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

Comment: Scrapy " https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/